# All the project files showing as Miscellaneous Files. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I moved my Asp.net-mvc project from desktop to F drive and all the files are showing as miscellaneous files.

I've tried running the visual studio installer and modify to make sure that "Nuget targets and build tasks" are ticked.

I've also tried :

1. excluding the file
2. add existing member(adding the file again)

but nothing's working.

Same thing happened with my asp.net core web api when I moved it, it's working fine tho, getting data from server.

Comment: Create new project to your desired destination. paste all project content over there.hope this will help you.

Comment: @AsifRaza  Thanks for the suggestion but I've been working on this project for months, installing nuget packages, connecting with APIs, adding components and all stuff, I cannot just copy them and get the project working, can I?

Comment: Try it, after paste whole content of project, then restore nugutpackges.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will solve your problem

**Solution 1:**

Create new project then paste all project contents in new created project.Restore Nuget packages then Build it.

**Solution 2 :**

Go to the file which are Miscellaneous inside Solution Explorer.
Right click those file'(s) and select Exclude from project.
Add Existing Item to project, you just excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file property configuration is wrong.

Try this:

1. Right click over the File that has this problem
2. Click on Properties
3. Under Advanced -> Build Action, check if other than "Compile" is selected.
4. If so, change it to "Compile".

[Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ux8.png)